# WPF bind custom ObservableCollection to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm desperately trying to bind my custom ObservableCollection to a ListView. I know this has been asked a **lot** but I still can't rap my head around it. I tried to add two values to the ContactList in the code (my custom ObservableCollection) but they did not show up in the ListView. If I tried to add a Contact to the ContactList using the GUI, the values are added to the ContactList but do still not appear in the ListView.

I posted my code below, if you have any question or need more information please let me know.

custom ObservableCollection:

```
namespace ContactManger
{
    public class ContactList : ObservableCollection<Contact>
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Contact> _contactList;

        public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts 
        { 
            get => _contactList; 
            set => _contactList = value;
        }

        public ContactList()
        {
            _contactList = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        }

        public void Remove(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                ContactList contacts = new ContactList();
                Contact contact = _contactList.Where(contact => contact.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (contact != null)
                {
                    _contactList.Remove(contact);
                    _contactParser.Write(_contactList);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }        

        public void Replace(int Id, Contact newContact)
        {
            int index;
            Contact contact = _contactList.Where(contact => contact.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (contact != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    index = _contactList.IndexOf(contact);
                    _contactList[index] = newContact;
                    //following line writes the _contactList in a json file
                    _contactParser.Write(_contactList);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    throw exception;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace ContactManager.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region

        private Contact _contact;

        public Contact Contact
        {
            get { return _contact; }
            set
            {
                if (_contact != value)
                {
                    _contact = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Contact");
                }
            }
        }

        private ContactList _contactList;

        public ContactList ContactList
        {
            get { return _contactList; }
            set
            {
                _contactList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ContactList");
            }
        }

        public ICommand OnSave { get; set; }
        public ICommand OnEdit { get; set; }
        public ICommand OnDelete { get; set; }
        public ContactCard ContactCard { get; set; }

        #endregion

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Contact = new Contact();
            OnSave = new OnSave(this);
            OnDelete = new OnDelete(this);
            OnEdit = new OnEdit(this);

            ContactList = new ContactList()
            {
                new Contact("John", "Doe"),
                new Contact("Jane", "Doe")
            };
        }

        public void GenerateContactCard()
        {
            Contact = new Contact();
            ContactCard = new ContactCard
            {
                OnSave = OnSave,
                OnDelete = OnDelete,
                OnEdit = OnEdit,
            };

            Binding binding = new Binding
            {
                Source = this,
                Path = new PropertyPath("Contact")
            };

            ContactCard.SetBinding(ContactCard.ContactProperty, binding);
            ContactCard.DataContext = ContactCard;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(propertyName);
                PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View C# Code:

```
namespace ContactManta.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowViewModel;
        private StartPage startPage = new StartPage();
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            //I read somewhere that the following line would be bad practice
            //DataContext = _mainWindowViewModel; 
        }
    }
}
```

View XML-Code:

```
<Window x:Class="ConManager.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:components="clr-namespace:ContactManager.Components"
        xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ContactManager.Model"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContactManager.View" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ContactManager.ViewModel" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:MainWindowViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ContactManager" Height="500" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="#36393f">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="110"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContactList}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Transparent">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button Width="60" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#5c6b73" BorderBrush="#5c6b73" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="100"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>

                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.6,1.417" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" StrokeThickness="0">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../resources/img/add.png"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </Button>

            <TextBox Margin="0, 10, 10, 10" Text="Search" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="#5c6b73" Foreground="#E0FBFC" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectionOpacity="0.6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="10, 0, 0, 0" Height="40" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="20">
                <TextBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0, 20, 20, 0"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Resources>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Content" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="20, 0, 0, 20" Background="#5c6b73"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: you posted `public class ContactList` code twice. ContactList implementation is wrong: either you inherit ObservableCollection and use its methods, or use composition (create ObservableCollection property) - not both at the same time

Comment: @tobs: Why are you trying to implement a custom `ObservableCollection<T>` in the first place?

Comment: @mm8 I wanted to make a custom ObservableCollection so I can call the custom methods (`Replace(Contact contact)`) in particular. Also I intend to write the data into a json file so I thought it would be nice if the `ContactList` would do that for me. How would you have done it?

Comment: @ASh Would you be so kind to elaborate on the second part. What do you mean with "use composition", like create extension methods ?

Comment: Why are you then implementing (hiding!) the other methods...?

Comment: @mm8 Do you mean the part with the `new` keywoard, e.g. `public new void Remove(Contact contact)`?

Comment: @tobs: Yes, I do.

Comment: @mm8 As I mentioned in a comment above. After I make changes to the list (add, remove `Contact`) I want the new `ContactList` to be saved to a json file. That's the reason I was "hiding" the original methods. How would you go on about that? And even if I use the default `ObservableCollection<T>` the list view is still not updating.

Comment: It's not updating when you do what? Your custom methods don't raise any event.

Comment: @mm8 when I add a new `Contact` to the `ContactList`. I hoped that it would appear in the GUI but it does not. But I did update the  `ContactList` and removed the unused methods.